# RStudio: copy single dataframe from one project folder to another?

Tags: r

Is there a simple one line function to copy a single dataframe from one project folder to another?  (Windows)  I.e., not exporting the df out to txt or csv and then importing in.

Comment: in RStudio you can delete all data in the environment except the one you need using this code `rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "x"))` then save this data THEN open any other data and then open the newly saved data so both should be in the environment that could be saved to 1 file.

Comment: Good. Upvoted your question and comment.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you want to save the data into the workspace file that is held in `.RData` within the project folder.

This is actually just an external representation of the objects that were in your workspace when you closed the project last. They are simply written out to disk to the `.RData` file.

Imagine you had Project1 which contained one data frame named `df1`.

```
df1 <- mtcars
```

When you close Project1, `df1` will be written to `.RData`.

Now imagine you are working in Project2 where you have a second data frame, `df2`:

```
df2 <- iris
```

You could load the Project1 `.RData` file into a new environment using `load()`:

```
Project1 <- new.env()
load("~/Project1/.RData",env = Project1)
```

Now you can assign `df2` into that environment:

```
assign("df2", df2, envir = Project1)
ls(envir = Project1)
[1] "df1" "df2"
```

Finally, you can write the contents of that environment back into the first project's directory:

```
save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = Project1),
     file = "~/Project1/.RData", envir = Project1)
```

When you open Project1 again, `df2` should be loaded:

```
ls()
[1] "df1" "df2"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not already loaded into memory in R, one can use `file.copy()` to copy a file from one directory to another. We'll copy one of the Pokemon CSV files from the `PokemonData` project directory to the `datascience` project's `data` subdirectory.

```
getwd()
# show the files in "from" directory
list.files(path="../PokemonData/",pattern="*.csv")
# show the files in "to" directory matching pattern of gen0?.csv
list.files(path="./data/",pattern="^gen0*")

file.copy("../PokemonData/gen01.csv",
          "./data/gen01.csv")

# show the files in "to" directory matching pattern of gen0?.csv
list.files(path="./data/",pattern="^gen0*")
```

...and the output:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/lgreski/gitrepos/datascience"
> # show the files in "from" directory
> list.files(path="../PokemonData/",pattern="*.csv")
[1] "gen01.csv"   "gen02.csv"   "gen03.csv"   "gen04.csv"   "gen05.csv"   "gen06.csv"  
[7] "gen07.csv"   "gen08.csv"   "Pokemon.csv"
> # show the files in "to" directory matching pattern of gen0?.csv
> list.files(path="./data/",pattern="^gen0*")
character(0)
> 
> file.copy("../PokemonData/gen01.csv",
+           "./data/gen01.csv")
[1] TRUE
> 
> # show the files in "to" directory matching pattern of gen0?.csv
> list.files(path="./data/",pattern="^gen0*")
[1] "gen01.csv"
```

The same procedure works with an R save file.